# How can I get the last day of the month as my end date on a BIRT report?

Tags: reporting, birt

I am having issues getting the last day of month on my report.

I used the add month function to add a moth but it kept on giving me the first day of the next month. I only want the last day of the month as my end date and not the first day of the next month.

Comment: And if you subtract one day from the first of next month, you get the last of this month.

Answer (score 0):

To get the last day of the current month enter the following Javascript:

```
now = new Date();
new Date (new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() +1 , 1) - 1);
```

[image]